# How can I limit the number of changes that can be changed with a set in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Well, for example what I want is to limit the changes that are madein the **SET**, that is, I would like the property c.es_tenista to be changed for 5 people, I tried with the word LIMIT but it does not work. Any ideas?

```
MATCH (c:Persona)
WHERE NOT (c)-[:JUEGA_A]->(d:Deporte{name:'tenis'}) 
SET c:Model_Data, c.es_tenista=0 LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIMIT can only be applied to WITH or RETURN. In this case, you need a WITH clause to apply the LIMIT before you SET.

```
MATCH (c:Persona)
WHERE NOT (c)-[:JUEGA_A]->(d:Deporte{name:'tenis'}) 
WITH c
LIMIT 5
SET c:Model_Data, c.es_tenista=0;
```